# External monitor blacked out in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu, dell, external-monitor

I have a fresh install of Xubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Latitude D610 with an external AOC monitor connected. When I go into Settings->Display the external monitor is seemingly identified, but it remains black. Turning off the laptop monitor (in settings->display) gets me two black screens.

Does anyone know if there's a problem with this setup? Some other way to configure it in Xubuntu? Ideally I'd be able to like to use both monitors, but I'd also be happy to be able to get the external monitor working instead of the laptop's screen.

The Latitude has an ATI RV370 (Mobility Radeon X300).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some very good instructions for setting up your dual monitor in xfce:

[How do I setup dual monitors in XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make the monitor I described in the question description (the AOC monitor) work, so I used an older, smaller monitor instead. It immediately worked as an external display, and the instructions in your link helped me to set it up in dual mode.

Comment: (I upvoted this answer, since it helped me out. But I'm reluctant to set this as the answer since it doesn't solve the original problem)