# How to stop the fluent change / switch between work spaces?

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors, xubuntu, xfce, workspaces

I successfully got my laptop hooked up to my 22 inch monitor with the help of you in [How do I setup dual monitors in XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce). It is pretty cool working on Xubuntu on a big monitor (in 1680 x 1050 px). :-)

Due to some weird mouse cursor speed I am not (yet) accustomed to, I keep losing the cursor when I get to close the right edge of the screen. I already looked under in the settings under `Workspaces`, `Window Manager` and `Window Manager Tweaks` but wasn't successful concerning the mouse cursor movement.

My question: How can I (temporarily) disable the mechanic which enables all this? While I disable this, can I still keep the shortcut `CTRL + ALT + RIGHT` or `CTRL + ALT + LEFT` intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Use `arandr` to properly deactivate the laptop monitor and properly configure the resolution for the external monitor to resolve all wonky and weird looking layouts. (Although it might look pretty good already.)