# XFCE Display Setup

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution, xfce, xrandr

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on another PC, and decided to install XFCE (by installing `xubuntu-desktop`)
Everything works great, except XFCE refuses to store my screen resolution and setup.

I have two monitors, each with different resolutions:

```
---------------- -----------------
|              | |               |
|Left 1680x1050| |Right 1920x1080|
|              | |               |
---------------- -----------------
      |  |             |  |
```

However when booting and logging in to the XFCE desktop I get:

```
----------------- ----------------
|               | |              |
|Right 1680x1050| |Left 1680x1050|
|               | |              |
----------------- ----------------
      |  |             |  |
```

i.e. The screen resolutions are incorrect and the displays are the wrong way around.

I have an xrandr command stored in a script which fixes this perfectly, but XFCE won't run it at startup.

I've tried both adding the script to the Startup Applications list in the System Settings (using the GUI) and modifying `session-setup-script` property of the LightDM config (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)), and creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the settings.

None of these worked.

Also, might be worth mentioning, at the login screen (LightDM) the resolutions and orientations are correct.

Any tips?

[**Edit**]
Okay, I was asked to provide more information... I'm not sure what else I can really add, so I'll just try to clarify...

I have a working shell script with the `xrandr` command that corrects the display setup, but I cannot get it to run at startup.
The script works fine when run manually after logging in.
I have set the script as the `display-setup-script` and `session-setup-script` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent), which works for the login screen, but as soon as I log in, and the XFCE desktop loads, the settings are ignored.

As mentioned, I've also tried adding the script to the `Startup Applications` via the Setting Manager GUI, which had no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup dual monitors in XFCE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce)

Comment: I mention that I've tried the solution mentioned in that question. My problem is that the script isn't being ran at startup

Comment: @user137832 I recommend adding detailed information about what you've tried and what happened (and why you believe the problem is that the script isn't being run), by *editing your question*.

Comment: Just to check a couple of things... Could you post the contents of your script? Did you try adding a sleep command before the xrandr command to make sure the display loads before the script runs? Try... #bin/bash sleep 5 && [your xrandr command here] If 5 seconds doesn't work then increase to 10. Let us know the results.