# Desktop region is limited on Xubuntu

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce, xinerama

I'm using three display setup and Xubuntu 13.10.

The useful region of desktops are limited. I can't place icons beyond some region in the center of the screen.

Please see the screenshot of my **primary** display:
[image: Primary display desktop]

For example I can't move *Firefox* icon higher than it is now. And I can't move *PhpStorm* icon lower that it is now.

Here's my NVidia configuration:
[image: NVidia configuration window]

Why is that? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Xfce `4.10` has only limited support for multiple monitors. The upcoming `4.12` is better at that (see [design/xfce4-settings/display](http://wiki.xfce.org/design/xfce4-settings/display) for details). You can try installing the (unreleased) 4.12 from [ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12) to see if it fixes your problems.

Additionally, did you try to set up the monitors properly by using `arandr`?  Or perhaps you simply need to follow the advice in this question: [How do I setup dual monitors in XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce).

Comment: Oh, no I did not. I will give it a try, thanks!