# How to make PXE boot auto detect monitors and setup dual monitors

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xfce, monitor

I'm currently can boot a Ubuntu PXE.
but the problem is with multi-monitors.
I have to run xrandr command to get the dual monitors up. with suggest from [How do I setup dual monitors in XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce)

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1
```

So is there anyway I can make it auto detect if there is more than 2 monitors and auto join 2 monitors.
I'm using XFCE
Really thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: [this answer to linked post with 16 upvotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce/356918#356918) mentions arandr which was OP's solution (see self-answer) so, totally a dupe imho

Answer (score 0):

Use `arandr` Screen Layout Editor to configure the monitor easily

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could add more details? It's not very helpful.